# Most efficient way to sort array of MM/DD/YYYY strings in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to use data from https://senatestockwatcher.com/, specifically getting the latest file. According to the API page, this requires getting a list of files in an Amazon S3 bucket, then finding the newest one and fetching it.

The code I'm currently using is:

```py
data = requests.get(url).text
data = xmltodict.parse(data)
data = json.loads(json.dumps(data))
data = data["ListBucketResult"]["Contents"]
filenames = [item["Key"] for item in data if "data/" in item["Key"]][1:]
filenames.sort()
print(filenames)
```

However, the problem I'm running into is that the filenames are formatted as:

> transaction_report_for_01_02_2013.json
>   transaction_report_for_01_03_2017.json

Using the regular python `.sort()` function for arrays isn't working as it reads the name strings left to right, and as a consequence neglects the year. What would be the most efficient way to accurately sort these files newest to oldest?

Comment: You should parse dates with ```re``` from the file names then try to sort them maybe by using ```datetime``` library of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With string slicing and `datetime.strptime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

transactions = ['transaction_report_for_01_02_2013.json', 'transaction_report_for_01_03_2017.json',
'transaction_report_for_08_03_2015.json',
'transaction_report_for_09_03_2015.json']

def custom_sort(filename):
  # assuming a constant string end length slice the date and parse it
  return datetime.strptime(filename[-15:-5], '%d_%m_%Y')

print(transactions)
#['transaction_report_for_01_02_2013.json', 'transaction_report_for_01_03_2017.json', 'transaction_report_for_08_03_2015.json', 'transaction_report_for_09_03_2015.json']
transactions.sort(key=custom_sort)
print(transactions)
#['transaction_report_for_01_02_2013.json', 'transaction_report_for_08_03_2015.json', 'transaction_report_for_09_03_2015.json', 'transaction_report_for_01_03_2017.json']
```

Comment: Here a repl.it to test it yourself: https://repl.it/repls/UnitedPlumMethod

Comment: @Aayla Fetzer If the filename is not constant, please provide the different filenames so we / I can come up with a regex (if necessary) or string split/join operations. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions ?

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^.*(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{4}).*$')
keys    = [x.match.group(3)+x.match.group(1)+x.match.group(2)
           for x in filenames
           ]

filenames = [y for x,y in sorted(zip(keys,filenames))]
```